# send email with gmail api not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail-api

I am trying to send an email, by using the google api in node.js

```
var sendmsg = function(auth) {

var to = 'foo@gmail.com',
    subject = 'Hello World',
    content = 'send a Gmail.'

var email = "To:  "+ to +"\r\n"+
    "Subject: "+subject+"\r\n"+
    content;

 var base64EncodedEmail = new Buffer(email).toString('base64');
 var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
 var request = gmail.users.messages.send({
   'userId': auth,
   'message': {
     'raw': base64EncodedEmail
   }
 }, function (err, result) {
       console.log('result'+result);
 });
};
```

I took this example from the quick start sample in google's documentation, that reads the labels in my email account(which worked fine). And I just changed the scopes to:

```
var SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/',
 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',
 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'];
```

And created that var = email

```
var to = 'foo@gmail.com',
    subject = 'Hello World',
    content = 'send a Gmail.'

var email = "To:  "+ to +"\r\n"+
    "Subject: "+subject+"\r\n"+
    content;
```

Then I am just trying to use the gmail.users.messages.send method.. But when running the result is returning the following:

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
   <TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
   <H1>Bad Request</H1>
   <H2>Error 400</H2>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Any idea what I am missing? I think the way I am creating my var 'email' is wrong, but I am not sure how it should be

Comment: Link to package you use?

Comment: I am using these two:
"google-auth-library": "^0.9.8"   
"googleapis": "^13.0.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `userId`-field has to be the senders email address (or `me` for short), the `auth`-object has to be passed in the `auth` field, and the message should be passed in the `resource`-field. Your message lacks a `From` header and an extra new line before the content to be valid. The message also has to be base64url-encoded:

```
function sendMessage(auth, from, to, subject, content) {
 // The Gmail API requires url safe Base64 
 // (replace '+' with '-', and '/' with '_')
 var encodedEmail = new Buffer(
   'From: ' + from + '\r\n' +
   'To: ' + to + '\r\n' +
   'Subject: ' + subject + '\r\n\r\n' +

   content 
 ).toString('base64').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');

 var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
 var request = gmail.users.messages.send({
   auth: auth,
   userId: 'me',
   resource: {
     raw: encodedEmail
   }
 }, function (err, result) {
   console.log('result:', result);
 });
};
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks Tholle. Also for the explanation.

Comment: @DanielMarín Great! No problem. :)

Comment: Tholle do you know where I can find the documentation of which properties I can pass in that json? (the one that I pass as a parameter in the  send function).. I have not been able to find it..

Comment: @DanielMarín You can only give the [`raw` parameter and a `threadId`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#request-body).

Comment: In the userId I changed 'me' by 'foo@gmail.com', but in both cases when the user receives my email he receives 'foo' as the sender in the inbox.

Then I tried 'YYY <foo@gmail.com>', so the user sees 'YYY' as the actual sender in his inbox. But it did not work. Do you know any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: @DanielMarín Use `me` as you did previosly, but change the `From`-header in the mail instead. `From: YYYY <foo@gmail.com>`

Comment: I had even removed the from header, since I noticed that I could write anything there and it would not make any difference. So I had not tried there. But surprisingly it worked. Thanks again Tholle, and sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of constructing the body yourself I'd highly reccomend using Nodemailers system:

```js
const sendMail = async () => {
    const mail = await new MailComposer({
          to: ...,
          from: ...,
          subject: ...,
          html: ...,
        });

    const message = await mail.compile().build();

    const encodedMessage = message
          .toString('base64')
          .replace(/\+/g, '-')
          .replace(/\//g, '_')
          .replace(/=+$/, '');

    await gmail.users.messages.send({
      userId: 'me',
      requestBody: { raw: encodedMessage },
    });
}
```